# MVC Store default values

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, default

I got a couple of columns in my database called CustomerID and ContentItemTypeID these have default values.

I know how to give them default values in my view but, I don't want to show the user the rows in the create view. So I want the default values to be stored in the code behind and for every item I create in my create view I want to default values to be filled in aswell.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hidden filled.
example : `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.title)`

Comment: Ah ha it works, I just need to find a way to store a default value